# Open a form using ID from a different form in Access 2010 using vba

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to open a form from a button in another form. The form with the button,contracts_all form, has a field ID and I want to open up the form that contains the information with that ID. This second form,contracts, has additional information and has buttons that allow editing of that particular contract. I have managed to get something but it's giving me a 'Run -time error 2489. Form contracts not open'
The code is below. Thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub Command74_Click()
    ID = [Forms]!Contracts_all![ID]
    DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "Contracts", ID
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim Rs As Recordset
Dim Test As Integer
Dim varBookmark As Variant

DoCmd.OpenForm "Contracts"


Set Rs = Forms!Contracts.RecordsetClone

    Rs.FindFirst ("[ID] = '" & Me![ID] & "'")

varBookmark = Rs.Bookmark
Forms!Contracts.Form.Bookmark = varBookmark

If Rs.NoMatch Then
  MsgBox "That does not exist in this database."
Else
End If
```

Comment: I tried this code..but it gives me "Method or data set not found" ..Am i missing something very simple here?

Answer (score 1):

I have the answer..thanks all for your help..what i ended up doing was get ID from Contracts_all form and each time I reopen the contracts form.here's my code

```
Private Sub next_Click()
    On Error GoTo Err_next_Click
    DoCmd.SelectObject acForm, "contracts_all"
    DoCmd.GoToControl "ID"

    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Contracts", , , "ID = " & Forms!contracts_all![ID]

Exit_next_Click:
    Exit Sub

 Err_next_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_next_Click

 End Sub
```