# Vba Access error: Method or data member not found

Tags: ms-access, methods, vba, ms-access-2010

I have been trying to open a contracts form from contracts_all page. I want to open all the records on the contracts_all form but only show the specific one clicked on. To show this one particular record, the button uses ID found in the contracts_all form.
I have managed to go this far with the help of various people in different forums but now I am getting an error which says "Compiler error; Method or data member not found"..
Please help!
Thanks in advance.

```
Dim Rs As Recordset
Dim Test As Integer
Dim varBookmark As Variant
DoCmd.OpenForm "Contracts"

Set Rs = Forms!Contracts.RecordsetClone
    Rs.FindFirst ("[ID] = '" & Me![ID] & "'")
varBookmark = Rs.Bookmark
 Forms!Contracts.Form.Bookmark = varBookmark

If Rs.NoMatch Then
  MsgBox "That does not exist in this database."
Else
End If
```

Comment: Which line is the error occurring on?

Comment: and this also refers to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17046407/open-a-form-using-id-from-a-different-form-in-access-2010-using-vba

Comment: the sub declaration was highlighted along with Me![ID]..The reference you provided is to the question I posted

Comment: which declaration?  and when you hover over Me![ID], what does it say?

Comment: this is the sub declaration: Private Sub Command74_Click()...I dont see anything when i hover over Me![ID].

Comment: If you're opening Contracts, is it opening as a new/blank form or one populated with a record?

Comment: Does ID exist on the current form or the new form that's opening?  You may ned to fully reference ID by using Forms!frmContracts!ID.Value or whatever the full reference to the textbox is.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you may not have the appropriate references set.  Make sure you have Microsoft DAO checked.  Note that these methods will not work in ADO.  :-)

Click Tools, then References, then Microsoft DAO 3.6 (or highest version available).  Not having the correct library referenced is easy to miss if you copied and pasted code into your project.

Cheers,
LC

Comment: I have Microsoft DAO 3.6 included in my project

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
Rs.FindFirst ("[ID] = '" & Me![ID] & "'")
```

with

```
Rs.FindFirst ("[ID] = '" & Forms!contracts_all![ID] & "'")
```

That may be slightly off, but I'm guessing it's because your active form has changed from contracts_all to Contracts, so you can no longer use the Me! reference.

Comment: I changed it.But now it does not find the ID..It goes directly to     Rs.NoMatch so it says "That does not exist in the database"

Comment: You're going to need to google a little about how to refer to controls on forms.  Without having the forms in front of me, I can't tell you exactly how to refer to them because I'm not sure which form has which control.  The answers are here, you're going to have to do a little work yourself to put them together.

Answer (score -2):

Another possibility is that the fields you are attempting to clear are set to Date or Number format, for example, which was the case in my database. I did learn a lot from looking through numerous threads on this topic though!